# Django to DjangoRestFramework - Where do I do form validation (I am no longer using forms.py - I'm using serializers.py)

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I used to use just Django but recently started using DjangoRestFramework. Without DjangoRestFramework, this was my forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput()) 
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput()) 

    def clean_password2(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data:
            password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
            password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 == password2:
            return password2
        raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if not re.search(r'^\w+$', username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username can only contain alphanumeric characters and the underscore.')
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username) 
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
```

I used to pass this form to the front end and then when users fill it out and hit submit, on the back end I would just do:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

to verify that the form validates. However, now that I am using DRF and serializers, I do not have anything in forms.py. I simply create the form on the front end like so:

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.add()">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username"> 

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password">

    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.passwordTwo">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email"> 

    <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
</form>
```

and when the user clicks submit, AngularJS sends it to the back end like so:

```
self.add = function() {
    $http.post("/users", self.user)
```

The URL the data is posted to is "/users" and the view which handles it is:

```
class user_list(APIView):
    """
    Create a new user.
    """

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

so the validation occurs when I do:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
```

With that said, the extra clean_username() and clean_password2() functions do not get executed since I am no longer using the RegistrationForm. Where is the correct place to do the form validation which I used to do when I didn't use DRF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform [validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) in the serializers, we can define a function `validate_username()` which will validate the username and another function `validate()` which validates `password1` and `password2`.

**Custom Field-level validation:**

We need to validate the `username`, we can add a function `validate_username()` to our serializers.

To specify custom field-level validation, we need to add `.validate_<field_name>` methods to our Serializer subclass. These are **similar to the `.clean_<field_name>` methods on Django forms.**

> These methods take a single argument, which is the field value that
>   requires validation.
>
> Your `validate_<field_name>`methods should return the validated value
>   or raise a `serializers.ValidationError`.

**Object-level validation:**

To do any other validation that requires access to multiple fields, we need to add a method called `.validate()` to our Serializer subclass.

This method takes a single argument, which is a dictionary of field values. It should raise a `ValidationError` if necessary, or just return the validated values.

Since in the `clean_password2()` function, you are trying to access the value of `password1` also, we need to do object-level validation by defining a `validate()` function.

**Final Code:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def validate_username(self, value):        
        if not re.search(r'^\w+$', value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username can only contain alphanumeric characters and the underscore.') 
        if User.objects.filter(username=value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
        return value # must return validated value

    def validate(self, data):
        password1 = data.get('password1')
        password2 = data.get('password2')
        if password1 != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
        return data # must return validated values
```